# What's the name of the character in Spider-Man: Homecoming's mid-credits scene?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-homecoming

And no, I don't mean Captain America.

Who's the guy Vulture is talking to in the prison, the guy who asks for Spider-Man's true identity, but Vulture tells him he doesn't know it?

Comment: “And no, I don't mean Captain America” — in that case, you *do* mean “mid-credits scene” rather than “post-credits scene”.

Comment: Logically, yes, you'd think so, but in the MCU they're all collectively referred to as "[Post-Credits](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Post-credits_Scenes)" and there's no such thing as a "mid-credits" scene.

Comment: maybe on some low-rent wiki they are, but here on Scifi.SE no-one gets to redefine Latin 2000 years after the fact!

Comment: If you don't believe me, Google "Marvel Mid-Credits". You might find a few YouTube videos being sensible, but almost every link will refer to them as "Post-Credits", or "End-Credits", or even "After-Credits", but _never_ "Mid-Credits". I agree that it _should_ be "mid-credits", I'm just saying that _nobody_ calls them that, including Marvel themselves.

Comment: I don’t disbelieve you. Even if everyone is telling you that something wrong is something right — even if the whole world is telling you to move — it is your duty to plant yourself like a tree, look them in the eye, and say, “No. Something that happens in the middle of the credits is mid-credits, not post-credits, you illiterate YouTube morons.” Pretty sure Odin said that. [The Wikipedia consensus is also currently “mid-credits”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man:_Homecoming#Plot).

Comment: BTW: in case you didn't recognize him (I didn't at first), he's the same guy who's on the ferry, that Vulture slams into and knocks into the water.

Answer (score 12):

## Mac Gargan, The Scorpion

This can be seen from his Scorpion tattoo on his neck, but IMDB also confirms that [Michael Mando](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm3103126/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t22) who plays the character, is Mac Gargan in their [cast list](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2250912/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast).

Michael Mondo confirmed this on his twitter
[image: Mondo confirming his role]

> STING  !!! Over the moon to be playing my favorite Super Villain! Heading to #SpiderManHomecoming premiere tonight to cause some ruckus
> <sub>Mondo on twitter</sub>